# How to check the percentage of downloaded files

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, download

I use selenium to get reports. I wrote the following code to check if the report was received.

```
    # switch to new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    # navigate to chrome downloads
    driver.get('chrome://downloads')
    # define the endTime
    endTime = time.time()+20
    downloadPercentage = driver.execute_script(
                "return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#progress').value")
    print(downloadPercentage)
```

But on the last line I get the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Comment: Hello there.  Can you check if you need to change the first query part like this :                        querySelector('downloads-manager')  -->  querySelector('#downloads-manager')      The other selectors has # in front of the id/name parts.

Answer (score 1):

'#progress' is not an input field to get its value with `querySelector('#progress').value` you need to modify it to `querySelector('#progress').getAttribute('value')`.

so, modify

```
downloadPercentage = driver.execute_script(
                "return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#progress').value")
```

to

```
e = driver.find_element_by_id('progress')
downloadPercentage = e.get_attribute("value")
```

**(Updated on 2021-02-01, based on comment)**

Comment: ```selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null```

Comment: Updated  based on comment

Comment: I finally solved it by opening the list of currently downloaded files and calculating them.

Comment: Yes. But it failed as follows  ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="progress"]"}
```

Comment: I think this error could occur if the downloading has been finished. Google, change the DOM contents dynamically. so, does that error occure during downloading, or after finishing?

Comment: The download is too fast to check. There are times when it becomes the current code and sometimes it doesn't. So I chose another method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228175/discussion-between-nour-allah-hussein-and-skw0314).

Comment: I will try many times and if I find an answer, I will leave an answer in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

I use another solution.
As soon as download started I switch to edge://download (chrome://download) page and start parsing it regularly (i.e. once in 3 seconds) waiting till "Cancel" or "Pause" title disappears.
When these words disappear (in fact converts to "Show in folder") it means the file has been downloaded.